# Ignore a property in the DataSource to check HasChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I got a problem with one of my class.

In Silverlight, I got a dataGrid, fill with my class Objects.

I add it a checkBox column binding into a property ÌsSelect` in my class.

I use it to check if the object is select or not.

The thing is, when I checked, Unchecked into the columns, it see a change in my Object, because the value of IsSelect has been changed.

Can I add, in my class, a metadata, or something else to tell my dataSource : 'Ignore this column to check if there is changes'?

I can use `[Key()]` to know the primary key, but is there something like  `[Ignore()]`?

I found something as NotMapped, but it tells me I am missing an assembly while I got

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

It seems, NotMapped exist only in 4.5, so is there something I can use instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as was as `using` it?

Comment: Yes, I already use the Key attribute in the same class, on another property. I am using this nameSpace. That's why I don't understand. Is is unable in .Net 4.0? Is there something I can use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which versions of .Net and EF you are using, but in .Net 4.5 [KeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations. Whereas [NotMappedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.

There is some detail here about where to find the data annotations with various .Net / EF combinations.
http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/ef5-where-are-my-dataannotations/

Comment: I have the tag .net 4.0 in my question. I assume, so, that I am in EF 4.